# Parsehub API PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv, web-scraping, parsehub

How can I dump the results into a MySql db? 
Specially decode gzip and parse it to an HP array then dump into a db.

```
<?php

$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","Aruns@cal");
if (!$connection) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_error());
}

$db_select = mysqli_select_db($connection, "arunslocal");
if (!$db_select) {
    die("Database selection failed: " . mysqli_error());
}

$params = http_build_query(array(
  "api_key" => "xxxxxxx",
  "format" => "JSON"
));

$result = file_get_contents(
    'https://www.parsehub.com/api/v2/projects/tmnx0bN0Ty0U/last_ready_run/data?'.$params,
    false,
    stream_context_create(array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => 'GET'
        )
    ))
);

echo "1"; 
$arr = json_decode($result, true);
echo "2"; 
foreach((array)$arr as $item){
    echo "3"; 
    $name = $item['name'];
    $value = $item['value'];
    echo "4"; 

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `arunslocal`.`scrap_yielddata`( `yield_name`, `yield_value`) VALUES(1,3)";
    //$sql = "INSERT INTO `arunslocal`.`scrap_yielddata`( `yield_name`, `yield_value`) VALUES('$name','$value')";

        if(!mysqli_query($connection,$sql))
        {
            die('Error : ' . mysqli_error($connection));
        }



    }
echo "5"; 
?>
```

How can I dump the results into a MySql db? 
Specially decode gzip and parse it to an HP array then dump into a db.

Comment: do you know what a insert does?

Comment: This is the responce i get

���8ZtqHycvgxB98L.csv]�1 �0н������v��N�:A<��J��`*�O�/ �s^�q�7�+?3��O6^>Np{�݅�w��'�����!�l�;�� ��ewaJIp_8�즃-T;Cu�<6W=��S����[���mQ$�G��BX

Comment: depends on what insert you are referring to..
I know SQL one though

Comment: what exactly is your problem?

Comment: when i remove the format param i get a json string so the api works

Comment: I want to get the results into a table. But the results i get in encoded or something. Plus the json result is not loading into an array

Comment: https://www.parsehub.com/api/v2/projects/tZELovmM4nqU/last_ready_run/data?api_key=tmgT6na5v3Me

Can use this to view the data in json

Comment: how do you load the json into an arraY?

Comment: $arr = json_decode($results, true);

foreach((array)$arr as $item){
 echo "3"; 
    $name = $item['name'];
    $value = $item['value'];
     
    }

Comment: see my answer below

Comment: That could be compressed. Check the MIME type in the result.

Comment: You also put your API key on the public internet. **Regenerate it immediately**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The data is gzip encoded

Your problem is the response data is gzip encoded.

As per parsehub's API [documentation](https://www.parsehub.com/docs/ref/api/v2/?php#get-data-for-a-run),

> The Content-Encoding of this response is always gzip.

**Solution**

Try decoding the gzip response.

You can use `gzdecode` to decode the gzip response.

Also fetch the API with format json instead.

You can then `json_decode` to convert it into an array and use it.

**Example**

```
<?php
    $params = http_build_query(array(
      "api_key" => "xxxxxx",
      "format" => "json"
    ));

    $result = file_get_contents(
        'https://www.parsehub.com/api/v2/projects/tmnx0bN0Ty0U/last_ready_run/data?'.$params,
        false,
        stream_context_create(array(
            'http' => array(
                'method' => 'GET'
            )
        ))
    );
    $result = gzdecode($result);
    echo $result;
    $parsed_result = json_decode($result, true);
    $yield_data = $parsed_result['yield_data'];
    foreach($yield_data as $item){
        $name = $item['name'];
        $value = $item['value'];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO `arunslocal`.`scrap_yielddata`( `yield_name`, `yield_value`) VALUES('{$name}',{$value})";

        if(!mysqli_query($connection,$sql)) {
            die('Error : ' . mysqli_error($connection));
        }
    }
?>
```

**Output**

```
{
 "yield_data": [
  {
   "name": "Sri Lanka 3M",
   "value": "7.760"
  },
  {
   "name": "Sri Lanka 6M",
   "value": "8.500"
  },
  {
   "name": "Sri Lanka 1Y",
   "value": "9.054"
  },
  {
   "name": "Sri Lanka 2Y",
   "value": "9.283"
  },
  {
   "name": "Sri Lanka 3Y",
   "value": "9.588"
  },
  {
   "name": "Sri Lanka 4Y",
   "value": "9.850"
  },
  {
   "name": "Sri Lanka 5Y",
   "value": "10.000"
  },
  {
   "name": "Sri Lanka 6Y",
   "value": "10.100"
  },
  {
   "name": "Sri Lanka 7Y",
   "value": "10.150"
  },
  {
   "name": "Sri Lanka 8Y",
   "value": "10.200"
  },
  {
   "name": "Sri Lanka 9Y",
   "value": "10.250"
  },
  {
   "name": "Sri Lanka 10Y",
   "value": "10.300"
  },
  {
   "name": "Sri Lanka 15Y",
   "value": "10.575"
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Updated the question with the modifications. how to handle the gzip part?

Comment: updated the answer, check it now for the complete solution

Comment: glad that I could be of help, If the solution worked, you can accept the answer. Thanks machi.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over the `yield_data` array
Try the following:

```
$arr = json_decode($results, true);
 foreach($arr['yield_data'] as $item) { 
   $name = $item['name'];
   $value = $item['value'];
 }
```

[demo](https://ideone.com/Frt7xO#stdin)

Comment: what echo 3 and 4?